# Find reference to (misspelt) object in sql server stored procs

Tags: sql-server-2005

I know that in a sql database stored proc, there is a misspelt (therefore non existant)sq object. What would be the best way to search the body of every stored proc in the database for this string?

This would be the equivalent of find all references in visual studio so very useful.

Server is sql server 2005.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(m.object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id), o.type_desc
    FROM sys.sql_modules        m
        INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition like '%whatever%'
```

it will search in stored procedures, functions and views for your "whatever" string.

Here is the simplest version (eliminates the object type from the results):

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(m.object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id)
    FROM sys.sql_modules  m
    WHERE m.definition like '%whatever%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could produce a single script for all the stored procs in a database, and then search that.

Right click on the databse, and go to "Generate Scripts"....  should be fairly obvious from there...

Comment: I sound very naive with sql server but I thought that would get the  stored proc object names but not the body of the stored procs in the resulting output?

Comment: No, you can 'script out' all the stored procs (as create proc commands) into a single doc.  I use it to generate a 'Build Script' for all my stored procs, as an additional way to back them up.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%YourTableName%'
```

There other ways, such as checking the information_schema.routines, joining to sys.sql_modules.